# connection error while using requests.post using python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=rootca, cert=(client_cert, client_key))
```

When I execute the code in CURL it's working fine. But got the below error while running it in Python3.

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=10.38.23.432, port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /users

Below is the CURL command:

```
 curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -XPOST 10.38.23.432:8080/users -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "abc"}' --cacert /users/serverca.pem --cert /users/clientcert.pem --key /users/clientkey.pem
```

Comment: Please provide parameters (`url`, `data` etc) and cURL command if possible.

Comment: Hi @miszcz2137 below is the cURL command

curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -XPOST https://10.38.23.432:8080/users -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "abc"}' --cacert /users/serverca.pem --cert /users/clientcert.pem --key /users/clientkey.pem

Comment: We would also like if you could give us the value of the `url` parameter. It seems that the python code tries to open a HTTPS connection, while the curl seems to open a unencrypted HTTP connection.

Comment: Hi @JeanHominal here is the url:  https://10.38.23.432:8080/users